# Slurm jobs result in abnormal execution times

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, slurm, hpc

I have a job script as such,

```
#!/bin/bash 
#SBATCH -p cs
#SBATCH -e %j.err
#SBATCH --time=40:00
#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1

# executable
for I in $(seq 32)
do
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 &&
    srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=2  bash -c "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-2.txt" 
done
```

And I have the same job script for different number of omp threads, where I only change the header information of **--cpus-per-task** = *number of openmp threads*, and also the one in the srun command.

It is weird that, among those 32 experiments done by the same job, although there is a general pattern in execution times,  some runs glitches with 20 times, or 350 times more execution time than the general pattern execution time. Debug program measures wall clock time as the program is parallel. It measures a nested for loop which is not interrupted by any other methods.

I run the scripts serially and manually, whenever one script finishes I submit the other one with more threads.

I have all the measurements as contained in the lists below,

[image]

Any idea why this could happen? How to fix it and get roughly homogenous execution times?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the Slurm cluster is configured, your job could be subject to perturbations due to other jobs, especially if the disk or network is involved, or if the memory is overused by other jobs and Slurm is not configured to contain it.

What you can do is

- use `--exclusive` to make sure your job is the only job on the node
- copy all input data/output result to a disk local to the noid to avoid network load interference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am now using --exclusive but the abnormal execution times still persist. My inputs are generated at run-time, which is not included in the wall time measurement anyway. I'm guessing if the threads are accessing to the same memory location during different iterations of the measured loop, this could create some memory bandwith problems or access latencies.

Comment: I have a memory-bound problem, and just did some experiments by trying to avoid memory reads with a trivial replacement of the code to see whether the outliers are due to memory delays. Runs that'd normally take 30secs now take 1 seconds and it is the general pattern without any outliers. I kind of confirmed the outliers occured to the accesses to same physical locations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just solved this case too. Apparently there was a minor error in my openmp pragma, wheere I assumed variables to be declared as private, but, when there is no default clause specified, it is shared. So I computed shared variables in N^2 iterations by each thread, which created bottlenecek s in some experiments. I would have expected the runtime to be inflated for more runs than the current few outliers with the existence of this bug. Fixing the declaration mode as private stabilized all time measurements in 32 experiments anyway.